# MikTex 2.9 fails to install on windows 8.1

Tags: miktex, windows

I tried to install MikTex 2.9 on windows 8.1, but the operation failed with the following error:

MikTex setup wizard

The operation failed for some reason

Details: C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex2.9\miktex/bin\initexmf.exe

Does anyone know how to fix this please ??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe you can try TeX Live, instead.

Comment: @egreg problem solved thnx

Answer (score 1):

### Try this,

1. Right click on My PC/My Computer and select properties. (Should lead to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System)
2. Select "advanced system settings"
3. Under the advanced tab click "Environment variables"
4. Find PATHEXE in the user AND system variables. If it's not there, insert .EXE into the lists of extensions. Make sure C:\WINDOWS\System32 is in both of the PATH lists too.
5. Restart your computer.

[copied]

Comment: I tried that and it's working now .. thank you !!

Comment: kindly click on the answered (green tick)  to help others !